# D3 Horizontall tree - Collapse everything at startup

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Can anyone advise how to pack everything at startup? I want to display only the main node after start. Thank you very much

https://codepen.io/atymchuk/pen/rmJBjK `enter code here`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modified your existing code to collapse all the child elements to root element.

Commented the code changes. Hope it helps you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<!-- load the d3.js library -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.23.0/ramda.js"></script>

<style>
  .node {
    cursor: pointer;

    circle {
      fill: #aae;
      /* stroke: steelblue;*/
      stroke-width: 2px;
    }

    text {
      font: 12px sans-serif;
      fill: #000;
    }

    rect {
      fill: transparent;
      stroke-width: 2px;
      rx: 5px;
      ry: 5px;
    }
  }

  .link {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #ccc;
    stroke-width: 2px;
  }

  .tree {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    overflow: auto;
  }

  svg text {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div id="tree"></div>


  <script>

    function buildHorizontalTree(treeData, treeContainerDom) {
      var margin = { top: 40, right: 40, bottom: 20, left: 50 };
      var width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left;
      var height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

      var i = 0, duration = 750;
      var rect = { width: 140, height: 40, hDist: 60, rx: 5, ry: 5 };
      var tree = d3.layout.tree()
        .size([height, width]);
      var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
        .source(function (d) {
          return { x: d.source.x + rect.height / 2, y: d.source.y + rect.width };
        })
        .target(function (d) {
          return { x: d.target.x + rect.height / 2, y: d.target.y };
        })
        .projection(function (d) {
          return [d.y, d.x];
        });

      var svg = d3.select(treeContainerDom)
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

      //Changes added for collapsing starts//
      function collapse(d) {
        if (d.children) {
          d._children = d.children;
          d._children.forEach(collapse);
          d.children = null;
        }
      }

      var root = treeData;

      //Changes added for collapsing ends//
      update(root);

      function update(source) {
        // Compute the new tree layout
        var nodes = tree.nodes(root),
          links = tree.links(nodes);
        // Normalize for fixed-depth
        nodes.forEach(function (d) {
          d.y = d.depth * (rect.width + rect.hDist);
          // console.log(d.x - 0);
        });
        // Declare the nodes…
        var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
          .data(nodes, function (d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });
        // Enter the nodes
        var nodeEnter = node.enter()
          .append("g")
          .attr("class", "node")
          .attr("transform", function (d) {
            return "translate(" + (source.y0 || 0) + "," + (source.x0 || 0) + ")";
          })
          .on("click", nodeclick);

        nodeEnter.append("rect")
          .attr("width", rect.width / 2)
          .attr("height", rect.height / 2)
          .attr("stroke", function (d) {
            return d.children || d._children ? "steelblue" : "#00c13f";
          })
          .style("fill", function (d) {
            return d.children || d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
          });

        nodeEnter.append("text")
          .attr("y", function (d) {
            return rect.height / 2;
          })
          .attr("dy", ".4em")
          .attr("x", rect.width / 2)
          .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
          .text(function (d) { return d.name; })
          .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

        // Transition nodes to their new position
        var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
          .duration(duration)
          .attr("transform", function (d) {
            const x = d.x;
            const y = d.y;
            return `translate(${y},${x})`;
          });

        nodeUpdate.select("rect")
          .attr("width", rect.width)
          .attr("height", rect.height)
          .style("fill", function (d) {
            return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
          });

        nodeUpdate.select("text")
          .style("fill-opacity", 1);


        // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position
        var nodeExit = node.exit()
          .transition()
          .duration(duration)
          .attr("transform", function (d) {
            // console.log('removed id:', d.id);
            const x = source.y + rect.width;
            const y = source.x + rect.height / 2;
            return `translate(${x},${y})`;
          })
          .remove();

        // minify the rect to very small
        nodeExit.select("rect")
          .attr("width", 1e-6)
          .attr("height", 1e-6);

        nodeExit.select("text")
          .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

        // Update the links…
        // Declare the links…
        var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
          .data(links, function (d) { return d.target.id; });

        // Enter the links
        link.enter()
          .insert("path", "g")
          .attr("class", "link")
          .attr("d", function (d) {
            var x = source.x0 ? source.x0 - rect.height / 4 : 0;
            var y = source.y0 ? source.y0 - rect.width : 0;
            var s = { x, y: y };
            var t = { x: (source.x0 || 0), y: (source.y0 || 0) };
            return diagonal({ source: s, target: t });
          });

        // Transition links to their new position.
        link.transition()
          .duration(duration)
          .attr("d", diagonal);

        // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
        link.exit()
          .transition()
          .duration(duration)
          .attr("d", function (d) {
            var src = { x: source.x, y: source.y };
            var target = { x: source.x, y: source.y + rect.width };
            return diagonal({ source: src, target: target });
          })
          .remove();

        // Stash the old positions for transition.
        nodes.forEach(function (d) {
          d.x0 = d.x + rect.height / 4;
          d.y0 = d.y + rect.width;
        });
      }


      //Only children will be collpased
      root.children.forEach(collapse);
      // To collapse all to root element
      collapse(root);

      //Changes added for collapsing ends//
      update(root);


      // Toggle children on click.
      function nodeclick(d) {
        if (d.children) {
          d._children = d.children;
          d.children = null;
        } else {
          d.children = d._children;
          d._children = null;
        }
        update(d);
      }
    } // BuildHorizontalTree

    var treeData =
    {
      name: "Enterprise",
      children: [
        {
          name: "IT Department",
          children: [
            {
              name: "Team Lead 1",
              children: [
                {
                  name: "Senior Dev 1",
                  children: []
                },
                {
                  name: "Senior Dev 2",
                  children: []
                },
                {
                  name: "Senior Dev 4",
                  children: []
                },
                {
                  name: "Middle Dev 5",
                  children: []
                },
                {
                  name: "Junior Dev 5",
                  children: []
                },
              ]
            },
            {
              name: "Team Lead 2",
              children: [
                {
                  name: "Senior Dev 1",
                  children: []
                },
                {
                  name: "Senior Dev 2",
                  children: []
                },
                {
                  name: "Senior Dev 4",
                  children: []
                },
                {
                  name: "Middle Dev 5",
                  children: []
                },
                {
                  name: "Junior Dev 5",
                  children: []
                },
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          name: "Manager",
          children: []
        }
      ]
    };

    buildHorizontalTree(treeData, "#tree");

  </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. Why do items with no offspring have the same color as those with offspring? :-( The original code distinguishes it.

Comment: I have edited the code snippet for the color changes. Pls check.